# Facing issue while using WebPageTest Tool while testing my application which has MS AD Login Enabled

Tags: performance-testing, lighthouse, webpagetest

I am trying to do client side performance testing with **WebPageTest** testing tool. My application has Microsoft Login Feature. For that login one window is popping up, were i need to provide my credential.
Is there any way to handle the popped up window through scripting?

Or is there any other tool by using that I can overcome this issue and complete my testing?

Answer (score 0):

If this is using Basic Authentication you could achieve this by using the Auth tab under Advanced Settings on WPT. The resultant output uses the Authorization header. You may also use the Script tab to `exec` JavaScript on the webpage and submit the form, depending on your auth implementation.

[image: Web Page Test Auth tab]

Read more: https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2015/using-webpagetest-authentication